# UISplitView having issues in Portrait

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios

I have a UISplit-view that uses Table-views in the left hand "Master" area and it seems that after pushing several table-views on the Root Controller, followed by popping them off and all the meanwhile, rotating back and forth between portrait and Landscape, the button in portrait seemed to stop responding.

Upon further investigation, it turned out that it wasn't that it wasn't not-responding, it was that the area that was touch sensitive was sliding partially off the screen making the area that you could touch to get the "Master" popover was at the very Edge of the button making it extremely difficult to hit.  I do have a flex space, title, and additional logout button.

Any Ideas?

Comment: Post some code, maybe explain your layout a little better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that in the Mono-touch split-view template, has two methods in the Detail Controller, in one it hides the popover and button for the Master view while in Landscape, and in the other method it puts it back.  I was using one of those methods to add a fexible space item, text item, and logout button to the toolbar.  The problem was that because I was doing it in that method, it was adding them every time it went to portrait and somehow the flexible space getting added every time, was slowly pushing the touchable area for the Master Button, off the screen.  (The Button itself never moved)  After adding the items to the toolbar during the ViewDidLoad method, and not adding it again, resolved the issue.